# Why there is different versions of openCV packages on Anaconda website? Which one should I install?

Tags: opencv, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

[image]
Why there is different versions of openCV packages? Which one should I install?

Comment: https://docs.anaconda.com/anacondaorg/user-guide/tutorials/#using-labels-in-the-development-cycle | https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv/labels | Presumably the main package (without a label in your screenshot), unless you have some specific need for one of the other variants provided (which all seem to be older versions).

Comment: you should use the **official** packages, which live on PyPI. do not bother with packages from conda-forge or other packages on conda. they are not supported. if you do use them, talk to the respective maintainers of those packages first.

Comment: Most users should never use sublabels for any package. E.g., the `broken` label is how we mark packages to not be used; the `gcc7` are specialized builds intended to be compatible with the **defautls** channel. But these are completely contingent on how channel maintainers use them and have meaning only inside the channel. Anaconda Cloud auto-displays this information by default and it confuses users.

Comment: Also, for `opencv` specifically, I would defer to @ChristophRackwitz's expertise: you should probably install from PyPI if you want support from the OpenCV community. My comment and the duplicate marking are more generically about what Conda labels are.

Comment: the stuff on conda-forge _may_ contain additional library support. I've heard people use third-party builds to get CUDA or OpenGL. I'm still PTSD'd from when conda-forge wasn't a thing yet and random abandoned builds of OpenCV floated around on conda, which annoyed everyone.